# Update master workbook with another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

There is lots of questions about copying the content of one workbook to another that I'm aware of.

I would like to make a code that updates the workbook by importing the content from the other workbook without rewriting cells, just adding values. I want to make it that way in case the other workbook is corrupted or have some data deleted.

Some rows can be partially filled but the macro will fit the correct information in the right row.

Comment: Yeah, why not starting right now? Or have you tried anything so far?

Comment: how can you add a value without rewriting that cell?

Comment: I tried I just don't know how to approach the problem. I was thinking of having a loop that will look for a specific value in a row of the master workbook and fill the missing values from the child workbook.Using the if function to fill the blank cells in the row should work. Also, maybe create a dummy sheet in master workbook and then update the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying to copy over the workbook as a different name?

Imagine you start with

```
MasterWB -> sheet1 
ChildWB -> sheet1
```

You copy over such that you have this worksheets.

```
MasterWB -> sheet1 , sheet2(childbook)
```

From there it is pretty easy to do a concat on a third page. First create a third sheet. Next, concat the values on sheet3 with values from sheet2 and 1

```
MasterWB.sheet3.cellA1.value = concat(sheet2.cellA1.value, sheet1.cellA1.value)
```

Sorry for the bad syntax, hope this helps!

Comment: Never used Concat in VBA. I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: To be exact the syntax can be found here : http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat2.php They use & to concat strings

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :D